# A Simple Way To Edit And Delete files in a directory in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Hello I'm creating a simple blog using express.js, using a data.json file to create/update/delete, posts based on the **id**. 
And every time I do that, I use **fs.writeFile** to create and update markdown posts **using the slug data in the json array**.
So when I create a post named First Post, I get a **first-post.md** file on my **/path** folder.
The Problem: Every time I'm updating a file and use **fs.writeFile** I'm creating a new file path without deleting the old one?

Example:

> Updating the name data on the json array:

**first post** 
to 
**first post update**
I get a markdown file **first-post-update.md**.But the old **first-post.md** file still exists.

Is it possible to delete every markdown file on a directory path that doesn´t have a **corresponding link to each slug data** in the data.json file?

Something like this:

```
function deleteFiles(files, callback){

 files.forEach(function(filepath){

//Filter every item.id on data.json and get the slug params.

    fs.unlink(filepath, function(err) {

//If any markdown file don´t have a corresponding link to each slug data delete them.

    });

}
```

data.json example:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "name": "First Post",
      "desc": "Some description",
      "slug": "first-post",
      "id": "07cbc3854-7fa7-4451-883c-a9c8c87143ef"
    }
  ]
}
```

some example code to create and update posts:

```
exports.save = function (req, res) {

var slugTitle = slug(req.body.name).toLowerCase().split('.').join("");

  var description = req.body.desc;

 db.add({name:req.body.name, desc:req.body.desc, slug: slugTitle});

fs.writeFile("path/"+slugTitle+".md", description, function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("The new post was created on path/"+slugTitle+".md");
            }
          });

    res.redirect('/post');
};


exports.update = function (req, res) {

var slugTitle = slug(req.body.name).toLowerCase().split('.').join("");

var description = req.body.desc;

db.update({id: req.body.id, name: req.body.name, desc: req.body.desc,slug: slugTitle});

   fs.writeFile("path/"+slugTitle+".md", description, function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("The new post was updated on path/"+slugTitle+".md");
            }
          });

    res.redirect('/post');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered removing the old markdown file as part of the update process? You could retrieve the slugTitle from the document in the database prior to updating it, and then delete that file. I've outlined an example below, you could make this another function or integrate it directly into your update function. You'd want to put some thought into what will work best in your code, without too many layered callbacks.

Note that I'm using findById from Mongoose, but you could apply the concept to whatever system you're using.

```
db.findById(req.body.id, 'slug', function(err, slugTitle) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  fs.unlink("path/"+slugTitle+".md", function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted the old markdown file: " + slugTitle +".md");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi jhildreth.Thank´s for your answer, it make sense but applying this to the code get me a strange error. `{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'c:\my\path\my-updated-post.md']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'c:\\my\\path\\my-updated-post.md' }`.

Comment: I´m applying the code in this way:`exports.update = function (req, res) {

var slugTitle = slug(req.body.name).toLowerCase().split('.').join("");

var description = req.body.desc;

db.update({id: req.body.id, name: req.body.name, desc: req.body.desc,slug: slugTitle});
db.getById(req.body.id, 'slug', function(err, slugTitle) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  fs.unlink("path/"+slugTitle+".md", function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted the old markdown file: " + slugTitle +".md");
    }
  });
});

    res.redirect('/post');
};`

Comment: Hi Paulo, you're welcome! It looks like you're updating the slug title in the database, prior to identifying the file to delete, is that correct? You'd need to retrieve the old slug title from the database (which will tell you the correct file to unlink) prior to updating the database with the new slug title.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using a database system like MongoDB or SQL to do this instead. It's usually easier to use a database instead of writing all this stuff yourself. No need to reinvent the wheel, so to speak. It looks like you're already using one to store the meta-data, why not do so for the entire article?

That being said, yes it would seem that your initial code snippet should work.